# jackson filter properties without annotations

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

```
public Class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    ...
}

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.writeValueAsString(user);
```

How can I filter properties without using any annotations like @JsonIgnore?

Answer (score 8):

You have two possible ways using Jackson

Mixin Annotations :- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html

JSON Filter :- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter

Answer (score 5):

The example of excluding properties by name:

```
public Class User {
    private String name = "abc";
    private Integer age = 1;
    //getters
}

@JsonFilter("dynamicFilter")
public class DynamicMixIn {
}

User user = new User();
String[] propertiesToExclude = {"age"};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      .addMixIn(Object.class, DynamicMixIn.class);
FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("dynamicFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(propertiesToExclude));
        mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);

mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // {"name":"abc"}
```

You can instead of `DynamicMixIn` create `MixInByPropName`

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"age"})
public class MixInByPropName {
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      .addMixIn(Object.class, MixInByPropName.class);

mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // {"name":"abc"}
```

Note: If you want exclude property only for `User` you can change parameter `Object.class` of method `addMixIn` to `User.class`

Excluding properties by type you can create `MixInByType`

```
@JsonIgnoreType
public class MixInByType {
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      .addMixIn(Integer.class, MixInByType.class);

mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // {"name":"abc"}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit slow but I use two phase copying. Firstly using spring BeanUtils secondly using Jackson.

```java
public static void copyWithIgnore(final Object source, final Object target, final String... ignoreProperties) {

    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        final Object ignoredSource;

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(ignoreProperties)) {
            ignoredSource = source;
        } else {
            ignoredSource = source.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, ignoredSource, ignoreProperties);
        }

        mapper.readerForUpdating(target).readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(ignoredSource));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot deserialize and instantiate source class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called [Squiggly Filter](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson), which selects fields based on a subset of the Facebook Graph API syntax.  For example, to select the zipCode of the address field of the user object, you would use the query string `?fields=address{zipCode}`.  One of the advantages of Squiggly Filter is that as long as you have access to the ObjectMapper that renders the json, you do not to have to modify the code of any of your controller methods.

Assuming, you are using the servlet API (which is not required, but probably the most common use case), you can do the following:

1) Register a filter

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>squigglyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.bohnman.squiggly.web.SquigglyRequestFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>squigglyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

2) Initialize the ObjectMapper

```
Squiggly.init(objectMapper, new RequestSquigglyContextProvider());
```

3) You can now filter your json

```
curl https://yourhost/path/to/endpoint?fields=field1,field2{nested1,nested2}
```

More information on Squiggly Filter is available on [github](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson).